Integral limits when deriving Riemann's prime-power counting function using Fourier analysis
Referring to this paper by Pranger (Section 1.7, page 8), I'm trying to understand how Riemann, in his famous zeta function paper, uses Fourier analysis to derive his equation for the prime-power counting function $J\left(x\right)$. My question is, in the integrals shown below, why do the integration limits change from $0,\infty$ to $-\infty,\infty$? I'm probably missing something really obvious, so please go gentle with me.


A change of variable: for $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, $x = e^{\lambda}$ is in $(0,\infty)$.

@KangyeonMoon - thanks for that.
